# Angular material table renderRows() does not work with matSort

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-table

I'm implementing sorting and deletion/addition to a mat-table.

I have been reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49284358/calling-renderrows-on-angular-material-table), which works fine without sorting.

When I use `mat-table` and `matSort` attributes on a table, `renderRows()` stops working.

[StackBlitz](https://angular-ivy-qpynkp.stackblitz.io)

As soon as I remove the sorting attributes it works again.

I found an alternative solution but it would be good to know if I did something wrong, has someone else made it work, is it a bug or intended behaviour?

Doesn't work:

```js
delete(index: number): void {
  this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
  this.table.renderRows();
}
```

Does work:

```js
delete(id: number): void {
  this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter( (item: any) => item.id !== id);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after splice() by index of item, you should update the datasource.

```
delete(id: number, index: number): void {
    this.dataSource.data.splice(index, 1);
    this.table.renderRows();
    this.dataSource._updateChangeSubscription();  // <-- Refresh the datasource
  }
```

> Working example link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rkpvf8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks! This works and the table.renderRows() is not even needed anymore.